# Overload of the operator <<

Tags: c++, overloading

Why there is no need to define an overload for "<<" having the following situation ?

The class

```
class T{
    int n ;
    int *pn;
public:
    T(int);
    T(const T&);
    T (int [5]);
    ~T();
    int& operator[] (int);
};
```

The main

```
int main()
{
    int tab[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    T a = tab;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    T b = a;
    b[1] = 0;
    b[3] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << b[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You never try to print a `T` (or bit shift one).

Comment: Because there's already an overload of that operator for `int`.

Comment: Which expression, in your opinion, should require an overload that isn't already provided by the standard library? What are the types of parameters said expression would pass to `operator<<`?

Comment: Thought this expression "cout << a[i]" might need an overload... isn't a[i] a T class type ?

Answer (score 4):

In both cases:

```
cout << a[i] << " ";
cout << b[i] << " ";
```

`T::operator[](int)` will be called which returns `int&`. `std::stream` defines `operator<<` for basic types (including `int`) so no custom `operator<<` is needed in this case.

You will need to overload the `<<` operator for `T` in case if you want to output the whole class `T`, for example

```
T a(0);
cout << a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only sending `int` to the output stream.  The operator

```
int& T::operator[] (int);
```

returns an `int&`, so on the lines

```
cout << a[i] << " ";
```

and

```
cout << b[i] << " ";
```

you are using the stream's built-in operator for `int`.  No special handling of class `T` is required, because no instance of `T` is ever sent to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is impossible to say whether you need to overload the operator or not. Its depends on how you are going to design the class and to use it. The fact that you do not use the operator in your main function does not mean that the class itself does not need the operator. For example as for me then this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
cout << a[i] << " ";
```

is not clear. What is the magic number 5? May I use other numbers in the loop? The fact that some constructor accepts as parameter int[5] says nothing because equivalent parameter definitions can look as int[10], int [], or int *.

So it can not be said surely whether your class need this operator on not.

Classes usually simulate some behaviour or some objects. It is not clear what is the behaviour of your class (whether it is a container or something else) and as the result it is impossible to say whether the operator is needed or not.